# How can I modify my ruby method so it takes in a block of code as well?

Tags: ruby, methods, yield

I have a method called myFilter that takes in an array, and filters out the elements that don't meet the requirement.

For example.

```
arr = [4,5,8,9,1,3,6]

answer = myfilter(arr) {|i| i>=5}
```

this run would return an array with elements 5,8,9,6 since they are all greater than or equal to 5.

How would I preform this? the algorithm is easy, but I don't understand how we take in that condition.

Thank you.

Comment: You wrote that you have such method, but after all, it seems you don't have such method.

Comment: can you show us the code in your method myFilter?

Comment: You are aware that `myfilter(arr) { ... }` is equivalent to `arr.select { ... }`, aren't you?

Comment: If you want us to tell you how to modify your method, you should probably show us your method.

Answer (score 3):

I take for granted you don't want to use `select` method or similar but you want to understand how blocks work.

```
def my_filter(arr)
  if block_given?
    result = []
    arr.each { |element| result.push(element) if yield element } # here you use the block passed to this method and execute it with the current element using yield
    result
  else
    arr
  end
end
```

Comment: The good practice is to supply `return enum_for(:myfilter, *args) unless block_given?` for this method to be able to be called without a block (lazy.)

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way would be:

```
def my_filter(arr)
  return enum_for(:my_filter, arr) unless block_given?

  arr.each_with_object([]) do |e, acc|
    acc << e if yield e
  end
end
```

More info on [`Enumerator::Lazy#enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-enum_for).

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
def my_filter(arr, &block)
  arr.select(&block)
end
```

then call

```
my_filter([1, 2, 3]) { |e| e > 2 }
=> [3]
```

but instead you can just call `select` with a block directly :)